# Subquery in Postgres giving incorrect result based on sum function

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.2

```
WITH eas AS
(
    SELECT 
    DATE_TRUNC('week',create_ts)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL AS DATE           
    ,COUNT(name) AS ase
    FROM local
    WHERE  type='sr'
    GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('week',create_ts)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL
) 
, ias AS 
(       
    SELECT 
    DATE_TRUNC('week',create_ts)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL AS DATE           
    ,COUNT(name) AS ase
    FROM local
    WHERE  type='sr'
    AND state NOT IN ('AZ','CA')
    GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('week',create_ts)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL
)
    SELECT 
    DATE_TRUNC('week',eas.date)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL AS l_create
    ,ase + asi AS count
    FROM eas FULL JOIN ias 
    ON ias.date = eas.date
    GROUP BY ase
    ,asi 
    ,DATE_TRUNC('week',eas.date)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL
    ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('week',eas.date)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL ASC
```

If I run the first statement it gives the following result:

```
3/18/18 0:00    21
3/25/18 0:00    46
4/1/18 0:00     25
4/8/18 0:00     25
```

Second statement :

```
3/18/18 0:00    67
3/25/18 0:00    129
4/1/18 0:00     148
4/8/18 0:00     138
```

If I run the full query :

```
2018-03-18 00:00:00 175
2018-03-25 00:00:00 173
2018-04-01 00:00:00 163
```

Whereas the desired result is :

```
3/18/18 0:00    88
3/25/18 0:00    175
4/1/18 0:00     173
4/8/18 0:00     163
```

What am I missing??

Comment: Well, for starter you are missing loops. There are no loops in your code. What you're doing is SELECT within CTE

Comment: "What am I missing??" Posting your tables's structure (as `CREATE TABLE`) and an explanation what you mean by loop. Is this part of an PL/pgSQL loop? Please show it.

Comment: But is a CTE not sufficient for this simple query? Sorry a newbie here

Comment: @stickybit, By loop I mean the "eas"  and "aes" part of the code

Comment: I'm just saying these aren't loops. They are select statements inside common table expressions.

Comment: @KamilG. Agreed! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is within the last statement. You're grouping by every column for some reason and performing addition here: `ase + asi`. Instead, what I would try doing is replace following lines:

```
,ase + asi AS count
...
GROUP BY ase, asi, DATE_TRUNC('week',eas.date)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL
```

with

```
,sum(ase)+sum(asi) AS count
...
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('week',eas.date)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL
```

which actually sums both counts of `ase` and `asi` for each date using aggregate function, so that the last part of your query would look like below

```
SELECT 
DATE_TRUNC('week',eas.date)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL AS l_create
,sum(ase)+sum(asi) AS count
FROM eas FULL JOIN ias 
ON ias.date = eas.date
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('week',eas.date)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL
ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('week',eas.date)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL ASC
```

---

To further investigate why this happens you would need to drop the `GROUP BY` clause and review the data to see for yourself what `FULL JOIN` does.

---

**Sample**

Below I'm attaching a sample history that reproduces your problem, but instead of date column I used integer (no difference for your case).

```
postgres=# create table a(dt int, cnt int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# create table b(dt int, cnt int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into a values (1,21),(2,46),(3,25),(4,25);
INSERT 0 4
postgres=# insert into b values (1,67),(2,129),(3,148),(4,138);
INSERT 0 4
postgres=# select a.dt,sum(a.cnt)+sum(b.cnt) from a full join b on a.dt=b.dt group by a.dt order by a.dt;
 dt | ?column?
----+----------
  1 |       88
  2 |      175
  3 |      173
  4 |      163
```

Comment: It works for me, I just tested that on my sample. Attached the code.

Answer (score 0):

`WITH eas AS
(
    SELECT 
    DATE_TRUNC('week',create_ts) AS DATE

    ,COUNT(name) AS ase
    FROM local
    WHERE  type='sr'
    GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('week',create_ts)
) 
, ias AS 
(

    SELECT 
    DATE_TRUNC('week',create_ts) AS DATE

    ,COUNT(name) AS ase
    FROM local
    WHERE  type='sr'
    AND state NOT IN ('AZ','CA')
    GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('week',create_ts)
)
    SELECT 
    DATE_TRUNC('week',eas.date)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL AS l_create
    ,ase + asi AS count
    FROM eas FULL JOIN ias 
    ON ias.date = eas.date
    GROUP BY ase
    ,asi 
    ,DATE_TRUNC('week',eas.date)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL
    ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('week',eas.date)::DATE - '1 day'::INTERVAL ASC`

This fixed it!! Thanks all!